# Disk with Maven in inteliJ

Tags: maven

The issue I'm facing is when downloading some libraries for my Maven project, it consumes 4GB of space, even though the .m2 folder is only 200MB. How can I clean up my disk now?

I'm expeting my disk is clean for more work.

Comment: What do you mean by: `is when downloading some libraries for my Maven project`? How do you do that? Via Maven as dependencies? And what is consuming the 4GiB? The project?